# MiniDFSCluster gives ioexception

Tags: exception, testing, junit, hadoop

I am trying to test in hadoop. have the code as:
    System.setProperty("test.build.data","/folder");
    config = new Configuration();
    cluster = new MiniDFSCluster(config,1,true,null);

but in new MiniDFSCluster(config,1,true,null), it throws exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "du": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.<init>(DU.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.<init>(DU.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset$FSVolume.<init>(FSDataset.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset.<init>(FSDataset.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.startDataNodes(MiniDFSCluster.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:124)
    at ebay.Crawler.TestAll.testinit(TestAll.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:92)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:41)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:463)
    ... 33 more
```

Could someone please give me some hint how to solve this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [`du`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_%28Unix%29) command is not there on the system or is not in the PATH. If using Hadoop on Windows then [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) has to be installed. Anyway, `which du` will give the location of `du` binary.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is because of the cygwin's not proper^^

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're using a Cloudera distribution of Hadoop. Version 1.0.0 of 'vanilla' Hadoop does work on Windows - at least create and writing to a file does.

If you need to run unit tests in a local Windows environment, try using Maven profile properties to set a version of `1.0.0` in you local Maven config, and in the POM specify the 'remote' config. The global setting will override the POM-specific one.

settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
          <properties>
            <hadoop.version>1.0.0</hadoop.version>
          </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>windows</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <hadoop.version>0.20.2-cdh3u2</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>
```